# C# select random numbers within a period of time

Tags: c#, random

I have a list of employee numbers (about 300 employees), each employee will place his fingerprint into a scanner and I have to `randomly` select **20** employees between **7am and 7:15am** and within a random interval of time.

All employees entrance shift is between 7:00am and 7:15am, Human Resources needs to receive an alert exactly after they place their finger into the door scanner only for the `randomnly` selected employee so inmediatly the employee is moved into a room for a special test.

For example, 300 employees will go in within a frame of **15** minutes, I have to select only 20 but don't want to be sequencial, so maybe the first employee will be selected but then second is not, and third is not, and maybe the fourth is selected again, and so on.

And there is other complex rule, once a employee is radonmly selected, the algorith will have to wait between 30 and 60 seconds (this has to be random also) until the random logic is executed again.

Here is an example in `Excel` of how it should work:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: I love the question. However I have a doubt first, if for example at 7:00:18, when there is one employee punched in, what would his chances of being selected be? Since the system doesn't know how many total employees there will be, would his chance be higher just because he was the first one in?

Comment: The _minimum_ 30 second interval allows only 30 selections in a 15 minutes period. With an upper bound of 60 seconds, you may get only 15 selections, fewer than the 20. Also, what does it mean to have 300 employees who go in, but only 20 selected? Are you saying that what you really want is a yes/no decision when the employees come in, and you're required to ensure that 20 will be selected? What happens if all 300 decide to show up early and wind up going through in less than 10 minutes, less than the time required to do 30 second intervals? The question seems incompletely specified.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your concern is correct, but that should be part of the coding, the code should cover that scenario (e.g. if the number of employees remaining is less than a certain threshold, modify the random selection to make it more likely to 'succeed' OR if the time is approaching 7:15 and there are not enough employees selected, once again modify the random generator to make it 'select' more often)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL the chances are the same as the rest. Well the system knows that about 300 employees should go in, maybe some wont but thats not a problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes thats true but there are more than one fingerprint, so was only an example.

Comment: @VAAA - The problem with this system is that it is possible to not select the required 20 employees if the chance of being picked is too low. So to ensure 20 you have to make sure that the selection probability is sufficiently high and that causes a bias - employees entering earlier are more likely to be picked. Therefore, if you want to avoid being picked you should come as late as possible. This is an unworkable system in the real-world.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL: _"if the number of employees remaining is less than a certain threshold, modify the random selection to make it more likely to 'succeed' "_ -- then it's not random. Frankly, the criteria that exactly 20 selections are made is in conflict with the requirement that the selections be made randomly. A true evenly-distributed random selection can, over time, produce an _average_ of 20 per 15 minute periods, but cannot _guarantee_ 20 for any given one.

Comment: @Enigmativity Shouldn't the bias be in the opposite direction? Once you start 'running out' of employees, the chance of being picked should increase.

Comment: In general, the solution to selecting a random number of items from a list is to order the list randomly, then take items sequentially from the new list: `var randomList = originalList.Where(x => someFilteringCondition).OrderBy(x => random.NextDouble()).ToList();`

Comment: @RufusL But according to your theory the first person will have almost 1/2 probability of getting selected?

Comment: @RufusL: that only works if you can shuffle your employees. And even if you can (let's say we know in advance which employee #'s will be arriving), you can't also meet the "no more frequently than every 30 seconds" requirement, because you have no idea (presumably) when each specific employee will arrive.

Comment: In addition to the problem noted by @Enigmativity, you also have the problem that even if you somehow solve all the other problems, an employee wanted to escape selection could just watch and wait for an employee to be selected, while there is less than a 30-second queue for getting in. Bottom line, your question is way too broad. The system itself isn't well thought out, and there are too many unanswered issues.

Comment: @Rob - The bias would be in the opposite direction if you can change the probability of selection. If you don't change it it is the other way.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL there is no big issue if we dont select 20 exactly, can be less I guess

Comment: @Enigmativity As yes, I misread your comment previously, I see what you mean now

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes totally agree with the 30 seconds problem, then we can do a random from 1 to 30 seconds and the employee wont know about it.

Comment: @VAAA - The only workable solution is to maintain a list of 20 employees that you randomly select from the 300. You do this **before** they arrive. When a person on the list arrives then they are flagged. At the end of the selection period if a few people didn't arrive then keep them on the list for tomorrow and then top-up the list by randomly selecting from the remaining employees. Do this daily. That way there is no bias and once an employee is on the list they'll be pinged the next time they arrive.

Comment: @VAAA To me, it seems like the requirements are far more complicated than what you're trying to achieve: randomly select employees to undergo a test when they arrive at work. So, simply assign a probability (6.67% will get you an average of 20 people per 300, ignoring the 'timeout' period), and pick an employee based on that. Anymore is overkill, when the use case is really 'I want to randomly select some employees for a test each time the swipe in for work'.

Comment: @Rob yes that could be an option also

Comment: @Enigmativity is a posibility to have a preselected 20 and then do the logic when they place the fingerprint. I didnt think about that option

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I am just helping (maybe?) with a method for choosing random items from a list. I'm not trying to solve this one, the requirements require too much thought, but there is probably a way to determing random login times (or time ranges) and/or login indexes of employees to choose for the test ahead of time. Then you just wait for them to log in.

Comment: @VAAA What happens when two of your selected employees show up at the same time?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was thinking more about shuffling login times. Just the beginning of an idea that I don't have time to explore right now. Will have to come back to this later, when I have time to try to put it to words (and possibly see that my idea is just vapor).

Comment: @Rob good point, only one can be selected.

Comment: Rather than randomly selecting employees, you could select 20 random times to the second between 7:00-7:15, once the random time is hit, grab the next person. If 2 login at the same time, do a 50/50. This is assuming all employees do login up to 7:15 and not all before 7:05 for instance. But you had this problem anyway. In this case the code can determine how many employees to select at one of the random times based on how many employees are left to login.